# DS18B20 with MOSFET - reading temperature from multiple sensors on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to read temperature data from 10 DS18B20 sensors, not connected in parasite mode.

It happens quite often that I don't get a reading from a sensor. I read online a bit about MOSFET's and they are supposed to boost the signal as far as I understood?

Is this possible? How would I connect it and are there any recommendations on the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use MOSFET like in this [guideline](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/148) from Maxim:

[image]

For best results, the 1-Wire networks should use Category 5, twisted-pair copper wire and have 5V bus power supplied by the master.

From http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/148

Comment: I've read the note and the diagram, and it isn't clear whether this requires 2 pins or one on the microcontroller.